# Purge documents by Date from ObjectId Value

Tags: mongodb, purge

I have to delete data older than 30 days, but I have _id filed, no date fields.
I am aware of timestamp conversion, but I am not sure how to use in script.

Comment: you can get the date from your objectId with [`ObjectId.getTimestamp()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/)

Comment: yes, but I am writing a javascript to do it, how should I take id and find older than 30 days and remove that doc

Comment: `db.collection.remove(function() { return this._id.getTimestamp() < new Date( Date.now() - ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 ) ) })` removes by the timestamp on the `ObjectId` value in `_id`.

Comment: @Aayushi do you need to perform a 'rule' based on that? I means, did you "periodically remove all dat older then 30 days"?

Comment: Yes Daniel, I found this solution to do it on the basis of _id field

Comment: @Aayushi if you need to perform "periodical delete" take in consideration TTL collections that is used exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Hi Daniele, I found one function, which convert "_id" to  to dateTime as required, When I need to apply query on _id field I pass that value to function it will convert to date and provide required result.

Comment: db.test.remove({_id : {$lt:objectIdWithTimestamp(deletionDate)}});

Comment: @Aayushi good, if you made "periodically delete operation" would be better to create an TTL collection. db.log_events.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } ) and mongodb will automatically delete the Documents for you!

Comment: Right Daniele, but here we cannot use TTL because we need not to delete data on periodical basis, we will use our script when required like to deal with space crunch